# Gitlab artifacts not appear at pipeline

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I would want to store the html report and let user to download it at Gitlab Pipeline.

After pipeline ran, I did not see the button to download report.

the variable is already set in project CICD variables.

```
  artifacts:
    name: "policy-eval-$CI_JOB_NAME-$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME"
    paths:
      - test-policy-eval-report.html
```

Comment: Check the end of the job log. Do you see that the artifact was uploaded? Do you see the artifact download button for the job?

Comment: Ok the job export report in json format. I kodified and it works. artifacts:
    paths:
      - test-policy-eval-report.json

Comment: Maybe it cannot find it in the root path, so you have to be more specific like /path/to/artifact.html

Comment: I added when: always seems working . Not sure why